# Error running C# program in visual studio code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I've been following  a C# tutorial video, now building a basic calculator and I've run into a problem(sure I've installed the right extensions to run C#...)

here's some code :

```
  static void Main(string[]Args)
  {

      Console.WriteLine("--------------basic calculator---------------");

      Console.Write("Enter a number : ");
      double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//stores number
      Console.Write("Enter another number : ");
      double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//stores second number

      Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);//adds 'double' variables

    //works the same as the previous program but it can calculate numbers with decimals now
  }
```

so according to the tutorial, the program is now supposed be able add decimal numbers and print out a decimal answer too, but the vscode says - The input string '' was not in a correct format. it tried calculating whole numbers though and it works it but won't add any decimal numbers

Comment: What's your language setting in the OS? Is it using "." or "," for a decimal separator?

Comment: The code looks good. Do you get an error when you run it?

Comment: Please provide the inputs you used and the exact error message received as text.

Comment: well, this is embarrassing : (, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @HereticMonkey already solved by jps, i'm a bit dense at times

Comment: ? jps fixed the code formatting. You are still missing the actual input provided and the literal, complete error message.

Comment: btw: `static void Main(string[]Args)` shouldn't even compile, so I guess it's a typo?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in this code it will work properly. I think you are not providing decimal values as input.
Please do not use single or double quotes when you are providing input values